# How to target a child element class and overwrite it's settings

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap and I'd like to amend the active class on this vertical pill nav to have no border-radius. I can't specify `.active` directly has that class is used by a bunch of different things

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Item</a></li> 
</ul>
```

So i'm trying

```
.nav-pills .nav-item .active {
    border-radius: 0px!important;
}
```

to no effect

Comment: And the issue faced is?

Comment: It would work fine, instead of border-radius 0, i added 2px, checkout here
https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-kowalevski-f5w1p

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sfuex89c/1/ ----- working fine

Comment: I think here the issue is you have placed `.active` class at the wrong place  try your `.active` class in `li` tag.

Comment: I'm an idiot, turns out my deployment server was cacheing the old stylesheet instead of serving the new one. It works as is -_-

Answer (score -1):

remove space between .nav-item .active

use this code :

```
.nav-pills .nav-item .active {
border-radius: 0px !important;
display:inline-block;
}
```

please note that between 0px and important we should have a space;
and a tag should has display inline-block for working border-radius